# How to add reactions to discord webhook payload

Tags: json, discord, webhooks, ifttt

I already did several webhook-payloads for my discord-servers, but I never managed to add reactions to it. I mainly use [this documentation](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/). I tried to check several resources for help on this, but never was successful.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another if statement like:

```
if (message.webhookID) {
  message.react(`reaction`)
}
```

You could also make it so that it would only react to a webhook on a specific channel

```
if (message.wehookID && message.id == id) {
  message.react(`reaction`)
}
```

If you have a

```
if (msg.author.bot) return;
```

statement, you would have to put it above that

Comment: This is a possible solution, when you are building a discord bot. But not if you are using a simple webhook to post messages to a channel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the text command `+:emoji:` in a message sent by the bot. (Not sure if this works)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not possible.